What are some arguments prominent philosophers have made for alethic relativism?
Alethic relativism is the view that truth is relative. I wonder, what are some arguments that prominent philosophers, both currently living and also those now dead, have made for that position? Because, to me at least, alethic relativism undermines itself, because if all truth is relative, so also is the claim that all truth is relative. But maybe some philosophers have argued that, while not all truth is relative, some are. I would like to see arguments for that view, as well as rebuttals to those arguments.

See SEP Relativism about truth and New Relativism.
